# What to do when an old question of yours is answered, but it's not applicable anymore?

Tags: discussion

What should I do when a question of mine gets answered long after I need/can test the answer?

I can't really accept it (I don't know if it works -- I'd have to test it, which is sometimes painful, and sometimes impossible, e.g. if I don't have the source code), but if I don't, then it would just stay on the site forever, never receiving an answer.

Ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Leave it be without taking any action. You don't have to accept answers to all of your questions.

Answer (score 2):

If you can no longer verify an answer as being correct for your question, then I would update your question saying so and upvote those people who have gone through effort trying to answer your question correctly.

In general if there are answers which might add value to anyone else I'd say leave the question as is - you never know, someone else might come along with the same issue and find a solution in one of the answers (which you could potentially always mark as answered at that time, if they post a comment about it atleast).

If there are more questions posted about your problem then it might be worth finding the closest match with more / better anwers than yours and marking your question as being a duplicate of it. That way anyone who finds your question, and has a similar issue, will have your original answers to provide help in addition to the answers provided to the other question.

Answer (score 1):

If you really cannot verify the answer anymore, just say so.
And give the answerer an upvote, of course; it's the least you can do for his/her effort.

If there are no answers, it's time to consider deleting the question.

If there already are one or more answers, I would prefer to let the question stand. Other people put effort in this now.
I'm not sure if you can flag your own question. Since you are no longer able to reproduce the situation that caused the question, you might want to flag it as "too localized".

Comment: Sure, I can give an upvote, but the main part of my question is: should I leave the question as "unanswerable", so to speak? Should it be ignored or flagged or something else?

Comment: I have updated my answer.